# Apache redirect to domain with ssl and not www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have two domains on my wordpress site: `example.net` and `example.com` and want to redirect all users to `https://example.com` (with ssl and with out www).

Link examples:

```
http://example.com 
http://www.example.com
http://example.net
http://www.example.net
https://example.com
https://www.example.com
https://example.net
https://www.example.net
```

Expression I use now:

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I tried to use some other standard expressions and they work somehow but this and all other solutions have the same problem. They don't redirect links to `https://example.com/category/` or `https://example.com/category/sub-category/`
Another links as `www.example.net/category/some.html` are redirected to `example.com/category/some.html` as they should. Can't understand where is the problem.

Comment: "They don't redirect links to `https://example.com/category/` or" - But why would you want to redirect this request? Where to? This would already seem to be the canonical URL (ie. HTTPS + `example.com`)? "Another links as www.example.net/category/some.html` are redirected to `example.com/category/some.html`" - What redirects that? The rule you posted obviously does not do that.

Comment: Sounds like a situation where using rewrite logging would make sense for the OP to understand what happens inside his own systems.